# How to access Magento Model data from a different scope

Tags: magento, attributes, scope

I am facing a requirement to access values for an attribute that are specified in another scope on a multi-website/multi-store site.  In particular, we need to display the Admin (default) label for an attribute in the frontend when the label for the Store has been set.

[image]

So the code should render the Hex value from the Admin column in one part of the page, and the textual Description from the English (US) on another part of the page. How do I do that?

Conversely, I have seen instances where values have been set on a Store View but are null for Default, and the code returns null even when the Store has been set. Can someone please explain how that works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to do it using Magento classes:

```
// Get the model of the attribute in question 
/* @var $attribute Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute */
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');

// Load the option collection for that attribute adding the storeFilter()
/* @var $collection Mage_Eav_Model_Resource_Entity_Attribute_Option_Collection */
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
        ->setPositionOrder('asc')
        ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())
        ->setStoreFilter();

// Load the product so we can get the correct option from the collection
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(39);
$productOption = $collection->getItemById($product->getColor());

printf("Default: %s, Store: %s\n", $productOption->getDefaultValue(), $productOption->getValue());
```

Adjust as needed.

Comment: Thanks Vinai, elegant and well documented. I would like to avoid doing a full load on the product, so I guess I'll add the attribute to the default collection attributes in my config.xml.  Also, is the collection of attribute options cached?

Comment: Depending on where you need the data (product list block by chance?) setting the `used_in_product_listing` property for the attribute would be enough, then you don't need to add it to the config.xml.

Comment: The option collection data is not cached by default. You could use collection caching to implement it quickly http://tweetorials.tumblr.com/post/10203426431/magento-block-caching

Comment: thanks Vinai, good point on the `used_in_product_listing`, re the caching, did you mean collection caching or block caching?

Comment: Ups, I meant collection caching of course - thanks for catching that! Here is the correct link: http://tweetorials.tumblr.com/post/9954764286/magento-collection-caching